# Vlookup in multiple columns at Python (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, merge, vlookup

I saw a lot of posts at SO asking for a way to do something similar to VLOOKUP at Python and noticed that most of answers indicates to use `merge` or `map` , but I do not know how to apply these functions in this case.
I Have the followings two dataframes (REGISTER and WEEK)

**REGISTER:**

```py
NAME   |PARTNER
Rafael |Roger
Sergio |Gabriel
Edson  |Ney
Alan   |Nelson
...    |...
```

**WEEK:**

```py
MONDAY|PARTNER|TUESDAY|PARTNER|WEDNESDAY|PARTNER|...
Rafael| ??????|Sergio|??????  |Sergio   |????????
Edson | ??????|Edson |??????  |Alan     |????????
Alan  | ??????|Rafael|??????  |Edson    |????????
```

The "????" should be replaced to something similar to =VLOOKUP('name in the left', REGISTER, 2, FALSE)

Comment: It is tricky, because **Pandas** doesn't really like when multiple columns have the same name, you should rename **PARTNER** with **MONDAY_PARTNER**, **TUEDSDAY_PARTNER**, etc...

Comment: Even if a rename, how could I apply the merge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with `Series` by `zip` of columns names filtered by indexing, so first column is mapped to second, third to fourth and similar for each columns:

```
s = REGISTER.set_index('NAME')['PARTNER']

for c1, c2 in zip( WEEK.columns[::2], WEEK.columns[1::2]):
    #print (c1, c2)
    WEEK[c2] = WEEK[c1].map(s)

print (WEEK)
   MONDAY PARTNER TUESDAY PARTNER.1 WEDNESDAY PARTNER.2
0  Rafael   Roger  Sergio   Gabriel    Sergio   Gabriel
1   Edson     Ney   Edson       Ney      Alan    Nelson
2    Alan  Nelson  Rafael     Roger     Edson       Ney
```

If value not matched, `map` create missing value. So if need original values for unmatched values use `replace` instead `map`.